# Use the same program to run multiple lines in bash

Tags: bash

(I found it really difficult to phrase the question right, please suggest an edit if needed).

Say I have `main.sh` and 10 python-files.

Instead of writing `python -u` before all python-files

```sh
#!/bin/bash

python -u file_1.py && python -u file_2.py && ...
```

in `main.sh`, is there a way to do just specify it once, like

```sh
#!/bin/bash

python -u (file_1.py && file_2.py && ... && file_10.py)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
for f in file_1 file_2 ...; do
  python -u $f.py || exit 1
done
```

The `exit 1` is needed to simulate the behaviour of `&&`: abort the script if any of the Python scripts fail.

If your files are literally named `file_1`, `file_2`, ..., `file_10`, you can even do:

```sh
for f in file_{1..10}; do
  python -u $f.py || exit 1
done
```

Comment: I hopes there was a way w/o using a loop, but I assume there is no around?

Comment: There are other ways but I think this is the simplest and cleanest.

Comment: With bash brace expansion, you could write `for f in file_{1..10}.py; do python -u $f ...`

Answer (score 1):

And there's also GNU `xargs`, if you have it. Exiting with error status 255 will terminate the current execution:

```
seq 10 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'python -u "$1" || exit 255' _ file_{}.py
```